Set StandardOutput=null in the service file which starts a script is equivalent to the redirection of the standard output of the script to /dev/null?
My current service and shell script
I have a systemd service file called myservice.service. The service is started at boot. The service starts the shell script /usr/bin/myscript.sh as you can see below in the section [Service]:
...
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myscript.sh
PIDFile=/dev/shm/myscript.pid
...

The content of the script is:
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/script-python.py > /dev/null &
echo $! > /dev/shm/myscript.pid

The shell script myscript.sh starts the Python script: script-python.py. By the redirection > /dev/null the standard output of script-python.py is sent to /dev/null and so it is lost.
Changes to use Service->StandardOutput=null
In the systemd documentation of StandardOutput I have read the following sentence:

null connects standard output to /dev/null, i.e. everything written to it will be lost.

So I'm thinking to execute the following changes to my files:

myservice.service becomes (add StandardOutput=null):

...
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myscript.sh
PIDFile=/dev/shm/myscript.pid
StandardOutput=null
...


myscript.sh becomes (remove >/dev/null):

#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/script-python.py &
echo $! > /dev/shm/myscript.pid

My question
My question is: if I make the modifications showed above the result is exactly the same of my current situation: all outputs of script-python.py is lost? There aren't any difference?

I think that's true.  There isn't any difference.  Was that your question?

Unsolicited input: myscript.sh looks like it was written for the older sysV init system where you had to do more yourself.  systemd will handle silencing, forking and saving the PID for stopping purposes.  I would replace that whole script with: Type=simple, ExecStart=/usr/bin/script-python.py and StandardOutput=null.

So I can change the section [Service] with Type=Simple, ExecStart=/usr/bin/script-python.py,StandardOutput=null and remove myscript.sh and PIDFile=/dev/shm/myscript.pid and I'll obtain a better systemd service with all my current functionality?

These two are nearly equivalent:
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/script-python.py >/dev/null'

and
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/script-python.py'
StandardOutput=null

The first one will redirect stdout of the .py script to /dev/null.  The second one will redirect the stdout of the entire sh script to /dev/null.  In this case, they are equivalent, but if your sh script contained other lines they wouldn't be silenced (just script-python.py).

As I mentioned in the comments, your script appears to be written for the older SysV init system.  It will work fine with systemd with Type=forking, but it explicitly does things that systemd would have done for you automatically.
If I were integrating this onto one of my machines, I would delete /usr/bin/myscript.sh and use this service file:
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/script-python.py
StandardOutput=null

You can see that this is much simpler.
As long as script-python.py doesn't spam stdout, I would probably also delete the StandardOutput= line and let journald take care of it.  I sometimes see people using >/dev/null because they manually run the script from a terminal, and want to re-use that terminal for other things without being bothered by the stdout.  That's not a concern when it's a service.
Here's an explanation of each changed line:

ExecStart=/usr/bin/script-python.py:  Systemd can run the python script directly.  This was not possible in SysV init. This avoids unnecessarily invoking sh.
deleted Type=forking:  The sh script you originally had, would fork (&), allowing script-python.py to run in the background.  This is how services used to work.  Since we're running script-python.py directly, we don't need this.  The default Type=simple causes systemd to monitor script-python.py directly.
deleted PIDFile=: This is only used with Type=forking.  It's a way to help systemd know which forked process it should be tracking as the primary process.  systemd makes a pretty good guess where there is only one child process, so it could have probably been deleted either way.

A couple of other notes:

Your PIDFile= is in /dev/shm/.  This is a strange place to put it because that device is usually managed by shared memory calls.  /run/script-python.pid would be more appropriate if you decide to keep this.

sysV init scripts would save the PID to a file so it could be retrieved later for stopping/restarting.  With systemd managing your service, that's unnecessary, because the PID is tracked internally, and the kill signals are defined by other options.
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
  start)
    /bin/foo &                # notice the fork.  foo will continue after sh finishes
    echo $! > /run/foo.pid    # Write the PID to a file for later recall
    ;;
  stop)
    pid=$(cat /run/foo.pid)   # Recall the PID
    /bin/kill $pid            # Use that PID to kill the process
    ;;
esac



Then users could start/stop the script with
/etc/init.d/foo.sh start
/etc/init.d/foo.sh stop

That has been replaced with
systemctl start foo
systemctl stop foo


thank you very much. I'll try to modify all my systemd services following all your suggestions.

One caveat.  Sometimes services depend on the environment set in /etc/profile.  That's not included when using ExecStart= directly and systemd has some very good reasons for that decision.  So if you have any problems with services that don't work after stripping the intermediate script, you can load that environment using the ExecStart=/bin/sh -c trick I showed at the top of the answer.

Thanks again. For now I have removed only the script linked to this question and everything seems to be working fine without your trick ExecStart=/bin/sh -c. When I change other services, I will remember this precious advice of yours.
